# Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations - Delete or disable a Fixed asset location

Tags: dynamics-365, database-management

EDIT: Last post was to long.

How do you disable a record in the fixed asset locations table so that it can't be selected when creating a new asset or used in other tables that reference that list?